# TypeError: FailedToFetch in Blazor webassembly solution

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, azure-ad-msal, webapi

I was building a Blazor webassembly app wherein I call a webapi using Microsoft Identity (msal).
When running my application (and webapi) in a localhost testenvironment, everything worked just fine. But as soon as I called the webapi from the deployed site, I got the following error message:

TypeError: Failed to fetch
at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.d__9`1[[AgroIT.POC.Scanner.Models.PartModel, AgroIT.POC.Scanner.Blazor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()

In my code I had the following definition setup within the Program.cs of the Blazor app:

```
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyAPI",
            client => {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            })
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

baseAddress was filled with "https://localhost:5001" for my localhost test; and filled with "https://www.somewebsiteiused.eu/api" for the deployed site.

Using Fiddler I found out that the request made to the deployed site did **not** include api within the URL.

The solution: **always add a slash to the end of your baseAddress**.  Because as soon as I changed the baseAddress to the deployed site in https://www.somewebsiteiused.eu/api/  (with a slash at the end). It worked!

Answer (score 0):

The above problem also describes the solution: always add a slash to the end of the base address for the HttpClient.

Comment: Move the "solution" part to this answer. It's a jumble now.